# Sqlite insert not working with python

Tags: python, insert, sqlite, many-to-many, foreign-key-relationship

I'm working with sqlite3 on python 2.7 and I am facing a problem with a many-to-many relationship. I have a table from which I am fetching its primary key like this

```
current.execute("SELECT ExtensionID FROM tblExtensionLookup where ExtensionName = ?",[ext])
```

and then i am fetching another primary key from another table

```
current.execute("SELECT HostID FROM tblHostLookup where HostName = ?",[host])
```

now what i am doing is i have a third table with these two keys as foreign keys and i inserted them like this

```
current.execute("INSERT INTO tblExtensionHistory VALUES(?,?)",[Hid,Eid])
```

The problem is i don't know why but the last insertion is not working it keeps giving errors. Now what i have tried is:

First I thought it was because I have an autoincrement primary id for the last mapping table which I didn't provide, but isn't it supposed to consider itself as it's auto incremented? However I went ahead and tried adding Null,None,0 but nothing works.

Secondly I thought maybe because i'm not getting the values from tables above so I tried printing it out and it shows so it works.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong here?

**EDIT :**
When i don't provide primary key i get error as

```
The table has three columns but you provided only two values
```

and when i do provide them as None,Null or 0 it says

```
Parameter 0 is not supported probably because of unsupported type
```

I tried implementing the @abarnet way but still keeps saying parameter 0 not supported

```
connection = sqlite3.connect('WebInfrastructureScan.db')
    with connection:
        current = connection.cursor()
        current.execute("SELECT ExtensionID FROM tblExtensionLookup where ExtensionName = ?",[ext])
        Eid = current.fetchone()
        print Eid
        current.execute("SELECT HostID FROM tblHostLookup where HostName = ?",[host])
        Hid = current.fetchone()
        print Hid

        current.execute("INSERT INTO tblExtensionHistory(HostID,ExtensionID) VALUES(?,?)",[Hid,Eid])
```

**EDIT 2 :**

The database schema is :

table 1:

```
CREATE TABLE tblHostLookup ( 
HostID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
HostName TEXT);
```

table2:

```
 CREATE TABLE tblExtensionLookup ( 
 ExtensionID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
 ExtensionName TEXT);
```

table3:

```
CREATE TABLE tblExtensionHistory (
ExtensionHistoryID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
HostID INTEGER,
FOREIGN KEY(HostID) REFERENCES tblHostLookup(HostID),
ExtensionID INTEGER,
FOREIGN KEY(ExtensionID) REFERENCES tblExtensionLookup(ExtensionID));
```

Comment: What are the errors you are getting on the call? Also, what is your full schema for the tblExtensionHistory table?

Comment: after you execute your insert you __must__ call `db.commit()`

Comment: @JoranBeasley: If he's getting errors from the `INSERT`, a `COMMIT` isn't going to help anything.

Comment: your right reading comprehension fail for me ... I didnt see that he was getting errors

Comment: You still haven't given us enough information. Show us the actual code, the actual values you're passing, and the actual database schema. We can't help you debug type errors without knowing what types you're passing in or what types your database expects.

Comment: Anyway, my first guess is that `Hid` and `Eid` are not ID numbers at all, but, say, a `list` of `sqlite3.Row` objects?

Comment: Meanwhile, why is this tagged many-to-many? For one thing, these are one-to-many relationships. For another, what reason do you have to believe that the FK relationships are even relevant to your problem?

Comment: And now that you've finally posted the code… it's almost exactly what I guessed. You are using `fetchone` instead of `fetchall`, and you're using the default `list` row objects rather than `sqlite3.Row`, but it's effectively the same problem. You can't insert a row (or a collection of rows) as a value.

Comment: What does sqlite3.Row does? @abarnert

Comment: @NottyShinchan: See [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Row). If you use it as your row_factory, each row you get from `fetch*` calls will be a thing that you can use like a list/tuple, or a namedtuple, or a dict, whatever's most convenient for your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to be sure without full details, but I think I can guess the problem.

If you use the `INSERT` statement without column names, the values must exactly match the columns as given in the schema. You can't skip over any of them.*

The right way to fix this is to just use the column names in your `INSERT` statement. Something like:

```
current.execute("INSERT INTO tblExtensionHistory (HostID, ExtensionID) VALUES (?,?)",
                [Hid, Eid])
```

Now you can skip any columns you want (as long as they're autoincrement, nullable, or otherwise skippable, of course), or provide them in any order you want.

---

For your second problem, you're trying to pass in rows as if they were single values. You can't do that. From your code:

```
Eid = current.fetchone()
```

This will return something like:

```
[3]
```

And then you try to bind that to the `ExtensionID` column, which gives you an error.

---

In the future, you may want to try to write and debug the SQL statements in the `sqlite3` command-line tool and/or your favorite GUI database manager (there's a simple extension that runs in for Firefox if you don't want anything fancy) and get them right, before you try getting the Python right.

---

* This is not true with all databases. For example, in MSJET/Access, you *must* skip over autoincrement columns. See the [SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) for how SQLite interprets `INSERT` with no column names, or similar documentation for other databases.

Comment: yeah I think your right ... `insert into TABLE (col_name1,col_name2) VALUES (?,?)` will probably fix it

Comment: I tried that too, its not working keeps saying parameter 0 probably unsupported type @abarnert

Comment: @NottyShinchan: As Humdinger already explained, you have to give us the actual code you ran, and the schema you ran it against, and the exact errors you got, not a vague explanation of what you tried and a loose paraphrase of the errors.

Comment: @NottyShinchan: No. Create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that's just large enough to demonstrate the problem, and post _that_ here.

Comment: Thanks @abarnert sqlite.Row solved the problem. It works like a charm now. :)

Comment: @NottyShinchan: `sqlite3.Row` can't have solved your problem. If `Eid` is a `Row` instead of a `list` or `tuple`, you have the exact same problem, with the exact same solution: You need to bind `Eid[0]` or `Eid['ExtensionID']` or `Eid.ExtensionID`, not `Eid` itself.

Comment: @abarnert all i needed was to fetch those those values and feed it to the table, by using sqlite.Row it did fetch the values and i added them. cross-checked it and they were right too. I didn't understood what you just said. Can you specify a little bit in depth please

Comment: `current.fetchone()` returns a row—whether it's a tuple, or a `sqlite3.Row`, or something else. `current.fetchone()[0]` is the first value in that row, which is what you actually want. Using `Row` objects instead of tuples doesn't have any effect here. It lets you write that line as `current.fetchone()['ExtensionID']` instead of `current.fetchone()[0]`, but it doesn't let you just use `current.fetchone()` as-is.

Comment: Yea i did some extra lines to the code to fetch the first element. It's working fine after adding them. Do you want me to edit it now? in the question? @abarnert

Comment: @NottyShinchan: No, you don't need to edit it. The point is that you need effectively the same extra lines in exactly the same places whether you use `Row` or not, so it's confusing to say that `Row` solved the problem. What solved the problem was using the first value out of the first row, instead of trying to use the whole row as a value.